# rails dates with json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord

I am implementing a *Facebook* application and using *AJAX/JSON*.

However the *JSON* structures that are returned have this format `2010-05-30T06:14:00Z`.

I'm calling `Game.all.to_json` in controller action.

How can I convert them to a normal date format?

Is it easier to do it from the server side or the client side using *fbjs*?
There are a lot of bugs with *fbjs*.

So i would prefer using a solution from the `Server side` using (`Active Records`). Like converting the data before sending the `JSON` structures.

Comment: That works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370061/format-date-time-in-find-operation-in-rails-3/7479550#7479550

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The way I added my own custom format to the json I was returning was to add a monkey patch to the ActiveSupport TimeWithZone class.

Add a file in the config/initializers folder with the following contents:

```
class ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
    def as_json(options = {})
        strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    end
end
```

Comment: This works great for me, but now I'm trying to do a similar thing for a Date object (returned using date_select).  I've tried replacing ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone with ActiveSupport::Date, but no joy.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Might be helpful to add %z for timezone.

Comment: @Geekygecko  I upvoted your answer. I used this approach and it works great for a datetime field associated with a Model, not for datetime field from other table in a AREL query with joins.

Comment: Ok here's a question: doesn't this completely destroy the functionality of the original as_json funtion ? If not, why not ? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280744/rails-to-json-uses-different-date-formats-that-to-s

Comment: With timezone, strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z')

Answer (score 7):

With timezone working in all major browsers and ie7+:

```
class ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
  def as_json(options = {})
    strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S %z')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Rails now has the `.as_json` method on the `DateTime` object. Life made easier.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this with client-side javascript, you can parse individual dates with something like this:

```
prettyDate = function(dateString) {
  var day, formatted, jsDate, month;

  jsDate = new Date(dateString);
  day = jsDate.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? "0" + (jsDate.getMonth() + 1) : "" + (jsDate.getMonth() + 1);
  month = jsDate.getDate() < 10 ? "0" + (jsDate.getDate()) : "" + (jsDate.getDate());

  formatted = "" + day + "/" + month + "/" + (jsDate.getFullYear());
  return formatted;
};
```

You'll need some additional code if your needing to format time of course.

Answer (score 2):

You can override method as_json in your model as:

```
class Game
  def as_json(options = {})
    super.merge(time: time.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'))
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Definitely easier to do it on the server side. You can do a gsub regex to put it into the format you want, or a time.strftime, then generating your json with that string.

Answer (score 0):

```
Time.parse < datetime >
```

simples.