# how to have rail 3 model to_json, return only the date and not time?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3, date, model, mongoid

I have a rails 3 model with a Date field. when i render the model as json, the date field is returning the date and time. It should only return the date, because this is a Date field not a DateTime field.

how do I make my model return only the date for my Date fields, when rendering to json?

i've tried overriding the as_json methods of TimeWithZone and Date, as talked about in [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883962/rails-dates-with-json-part-2) 2 [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937740/rails-dates-with-json), but that's not working for me.

fwiw, we're using ruby 1.9.2, rails 3.0.7, mongodb and mongoid 2.0.2. I know our version of mongo/mongoid does not support a "Date" field type, specifically. it gets stored as a UTC time. i'm trying to get the data to look like it's just a date, on the way out to the client via json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just override the date getter in your class (assuming your date field is called `date`):

```
class YourClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  def date
    self[:date] && self[:date].to_date
  end
end
```

This way whenever you call `some_record.date` it will convert the TimeWithZone object to a Date object before returning it.