# Format date time in find operation in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for a way to format date time in find(:all) so that when I render my results in JSON, the date time will look like

"March 20, 2011"

instead of

"2011-03-20T04:57:50Z"

Does anyone have any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so you want to render the results in JSON formatted nicely. Instead of changing the format of the date on the way in, change it on the way out.

```
class Post

  def formatted_created_at
    created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y")
  end

  def as_json(args={})
    super(:methods=>:formatted_created_at, :except=>:date)
  end
end
```

Comment: I did as you suggested but it didn't work. Here are my controller and model http://pastie.org/1693138. Thanks.

Comment: @Tri Vuong .. What was your output? Append to your pastie. (and you don't want to_json)... Your action should be "responds_with BusinessCard.order("created_at DESC").all)

Comment: created_at doesn't have the format that I want. I appended the output to pastie. Thanks.

Comment: Well, if you want created_at to be formatted, you need to tell formatted_date to format the created_at. I edited answer to reflect

Comment: @hipertracker Go ahead and open a new question with rails 3.1 and what you see is happening (it works in rails 3.1).

Answer (score 1):

I would have used `Date.parse(datestring)` on the client to generate some usable content.

Comment: @hipertracker No it doesn't. `Date.parse(datestring).class` returns the `Date` constant. `Date.parse(datestring).strftime("%B, %Y")` returns `March, 2011`

Comment: had some trouble handling json communicating to some js clientside
used this solution
does return an "int" in seconds since 1.Jan.1970

Answer (score 0):

```
Time.now().strftime("%b %d, %Y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, you could do something like:

```
@posts = Post.all
@posts.all.each do |x|
  x.date = x.date.strftime("%b %d, %Y")
end
@posts.to_json
```

Answer (score 0):

That works (checked in Rails 3.1), put it into config/initializer/times_format.js. First two lines fix default time format (e.g. AR created_at). Third part is monkey patch for JSON.

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%Y-%m-%d"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

class ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
  def as_json(options={})
    strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Look you use jbuilder? and for example index.json.jbuilder

```
json.array!(@textstrings) do |textstring|
  json.extract! textstring, :id, :text
  json.created_at textstring.created_at.to_formatted_s(:short) 
  json.url textstring_url(textstring, format: :json)
end
```

in this example I am use method  [.to_formatted_s](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/DateTime/Conversions/to_formatted_s)

```
 json.created_at textstring.created_at.to_formatted_s(:short
```

and i've got

```
[{"id":1,"text":"liveasda","created_at":"17 Nov 12:48","url":"http://localhost:5555/textstrings/1.json"},{"id":2,"text":"123","created_at":"17 Nov 14:26","url":"http://localhost:5555/textstrings/2.json"},
```