# JSON changing the format of the date in rails 3

Tags: web-services, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a datetime field in rails and it stores in the right format when I save an object from rails. But when I convert that to the JSON format, it messes the date format:

Format stored in the DB: `2011-04-27 09:18:00 -0400` but when I do JSON of that object it changes the date format to `2011-04-27T09:18:00-04:00`

How can I keep the date format consistent?

I'm using `render :json => @eventsList` to render the object to :json

Comment: That works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370061/format-date-time-in-find-operation-in-rails-3/7479550#7479550

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used the solution at [rails dates with json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937740/rails-dates-with-json)