# Rails to_json uses different DATE_FORMATS that .to_s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date-format

With the following in my rails_defaults.rb:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = '%m/%d/%Y'
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default]= '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'
```

Why do the following results differ:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :005 > MyModel.find(2).to_json(:only => :start_date)
 => "{\"start_date\":\"2012-02-03\"}" 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :006 > MyModel.find(2).start_date.to_s
 => "02/03/2012"
```

And more importantly, how do I get `to_json` to use `%m/%d/%Y`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because the standard JSON format for a date is `%Y-%m-%d` and there's no way to change it unless you override `Date#as_json` (don't do so or your application will start misbehaving).

See https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb#L265-273

```
class Date
  def as_json(options = nil) #:nodoc:
    if ActiveSupport.use_standard_json_time_format
      strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    else
      strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
    end
  end
end
```