# Rails - Don't want timezone in sql o/p

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails app on PGSQL and there is a Date of Birth column (timestamp without time zone).

I use a "select" to get the employee data back and return that as JSON, but the DOB always comes back with a timezone, e.g. "dob":"1992-06-18T20:00:00-04:00".

I tried using to_char(emp.dob, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), but no effect.

Any one has any ideas how to get the o/p to not contain TZ information?

Something like: 1992-06-18 20:00:00

Thanks

EDIT: Found the solution to a similar question here: 
[rails dates with json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937740/rails-dates-with-json)

Answer (score 0):

Use the localization method and type the following:

`<%= l emp.dob, :format => :long %>`

There are several pre-defined options to show the text (:long, :short etc)
You can read more [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats).