# Rails Time to String - either ignores function or acts randomly

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, time

In Ruby on Rails 3 I'm trying to modify my `Model` dataset's dates to only show hours and minutes, which I then return as an AJAX string.

My code is the following:

```
 list_of_time_fields = [:a, :list, :of, :symbols]
 result = Model.where(conditions).take(100)
 result.each { |row|
        list_of_time_fields.each { |field|
            row[field] = row[field].strftime("%H:%M") unless row[field].nil?
        }
    }
 return result
```

For some fields I get the whole time string (something like `yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:ssZ`) and for others I get `null`even if the field is not null. The difference is that the ones that return strings are `TIME` fields in MySQL, whereas the others are `DATETIME`.

I've checked the types to which Rails maps these columns and everything is `class Time`.

If you can point which things I should look at It'd be great.

Comment: Are you returning the data as JSON?

Comment: Yes, with a `render json: result`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When assigning the time string to the attribute:

```
row[field] = row[field].strftime("%H:%M")
```

Rails parses the string and creates a new datetime (actually a `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`) object instead:

```
user = User.new
user.created_at = "01:00"
#=> "01:00"
user.created_at
#=> Thu, 28 Nov 2013 01:00:00 CET +01:00
```

Using a custom hash would work. Something like:

```
result = Model.where(conditions).take(100).map { |model|
  {
    id: model.id,
    time_field: model.time_field.try(:strftime, "%H:%M")
  }
}
render json: result
```

[JBuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) might be another option.

Comment: Thanks, also just found it's the same case as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937740/rails-dates-with-json

Comment: Just a question, does using `model_return = model.attributes` break your solution?