# Customize datetime format for all datetime fields in JSON response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

I use jbuilder to output my data.

However, the date in JS will look like this `2016-09-01T02:39:08.495Z`
How could I make Rails output any datetime-type field with this format `2016-09-01 02:39`,  discard the timezone information in the JSON output.

It seems there's no elegant way to make this option be default.

That is I need to manually put the conversion into any field I want to convert for all jbuilder templates.

Comment: sounds pretty much the same as this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937740/rails-dates-with-json

Answer (score 0):

You can always use formatting: Time.zone.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%m")

If you're planning on using this in many places in your Rails app, you can add the foll. to your `config/application.rb` file:

```
class Time
  def without_timezone
    self.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%m")
  end
end
```

Then you can call `without_timezone` method on the Time object anywhere in your Rails app, including jbuilder.

```
Time.zone.now
> Tue, 23 Aug 2016 19:59:17 UTC +00:00
Time.zone.now.without_timezone
> "2016-08-23 20:08"
```